# Anchor links in a hidden div for Google Adsense

Tags: php, html, css, adsense

I have a verified Google Adsense account:
And I've registered domain in my sites list - `http://url.com/extra`

I have set up several single category blogs on a subdirectory:

```
http://url.com/extra/music
http://url.com/extra/fashion
http://url.com/extra/horror
http://url.com/extra/nature
```

Each blog/site is independent of one another and there is no `index` page to list each site - Most of my visitors are going to be from searches or social media/forums - so I don't feel the need to link them together in a dedicated home page.

The problem is that AdSense will not be able to crawl the pages properly and the sites appear to be hidden from sight.

So I'm thinking that if I create an `index.php` page, with a link to each site, but then hide the div that they are contained in, AdSense should be able to follow my sites, but everyday visitors will just see a blank screen, or a page with a central logo for example.

So:

```
<div class="adsense">
    <a href="music" />
    <a href="fashion" />
</div>

.adsense{
    display: none;
}
```

In theory I can't see a problem with this, but do any of you know if this would be acceptable way to go about things?

Answer (score 0):

AdSense does not need your blogs to be linked in any way. AdSense loads ads contextually and on a re-marketing basis. Meaning that AdSense loads the best possible ads for your user as he loads an individual page on your blog. Linking between your separate blogs will have no affect on your AdSense earnings or on the type of ads shown to your blog visitors.

If you are concerned about Google not being able to index/crawl your blogs correctly, its advised to register your site on Google Search Console here: https://search.google.com/search-console

Then simply submit XML sitemaps for each one of your blogs.